# Beutifulsoup parse, get information from child tag

Tags: python, parsing

I have the following "web-site" (here is the piece of the html):

```
<div class="moduleBody">
     <div class="feature">
     <div class="feature">
         <h2>
             <a href="somelink">sometext</a>
         </h2>
         <div class="relatedInfo">
              <span class="relatedTopics">
              <span class="timestamp">22 Mar 2014</span>
         </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

I would like to extract the **sometext** and **somelink**. For this purpose, I have written the python code, here it is:

```
for links in soup.find_all('div','moduleBody'):
        for link in links.find_all('div','feature'):
            if not("video" in (link['href'])):
                print "Name: "+link.text
                #sibling_page=urllib2.urlopen("major_link"+link['href'])
                print " Link extracted: "+link['href']
```

However, this code prints nothing. Could you suggest where is my mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your second `for` loop, your `link` variable holds reference to `<div class="feature">...</div>`, which do not have the attribute `href`.

It highly depends on your structure, but if the `<div class="feature">` tag always starts with `<h2>` tag which contains only `<a>` tag, then what you can do is to get the anchor tag `<a>` first:

```
for links in soup.find_all('div','moduleBody'):
    for link in links.find_all('div','feature'):
        anchor_tag = link.h2.a
        if not 'video' in anchor_tag['href']:
            print 'Name: %s' % anchor_tag.text
            print 'Link extracted: %s' % anchor_tag['href']
```

By the way, your HTML is not well-formed, the first `<div class="feature">` tag should be closed.

```
<div class="moduleBody">
 <div class="feature"></div>
 <div class="feature">
     <h2>
         <a href="somelink">sometext</a>
     </h2>
     <div class="relatedInfo">
          <span class="relatedTopics">
          <span class="timestamp">22 Mar 2014</span>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `div` does not have `href` attribute. You have to look one level down at the `<a>` element.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """
<div class="moduleBody">
     <div class="feature">
     <div class="feature">
         <h2>
             <a href="somelink">sometext</a>
         </h2>
         <div class="relatedInfo">
              <span class="relatedTopics">
              <span class="timestamp">22 Mar 2014</span>
         </div>
      </div>
</div>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

for links in soup.find_all("div", "moduleBody"):
    for link in links.find_all("div", "feature"):
        for a in links.find_all("a"):
            if not "video" in a['href']:
                print("Name: " + a.text)
                print("Link extracted: " + a['href'])
```

Prints:

```
Name: sometext
Link extracted: somelink
Name: sometext
Link extracted: somelink
```

It finds it twice, as your html is broken. BeautifulSoup fixes it as follows:

```
<div class="moduleBody">
 <div class="feature">
  <div class="feature">
   <h2>
    <a href="somelink">
     sometext
    </a>
   </h2>
   <div class="relatedInfo">
    <span class="relatedTopics">
     <span class="timestamp">
      22 Mar 2014
     </span>
    </span>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```